# Cannot insert array elements into database in asp.net. System.String[] is inserted instead

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

In asp.net I'm inserting array values into a database but array elements are not inserted properly. Instead of that, System.String[] is inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.String[] in the database implies that you are passing the string array directly to your database insert method.

Instead, you'll need to loop through the array and insert the strings as individual rows:

```
foreach(string s in stringArray)
{
    database.Insert(s);
}
```

Alternatively, you can flatten the array and insert into a single row like this:

```
database.Insert(String.Join(",", stringArray))
```

This would insert the array as a comma-delimited list.

Comment: Seems like you copied my mistake on String.Join

Comment: foreach(string s in stringArray)
{
    database.Insert(s);
} this is well for insertion but when I m using same loop for updation it doesn't work?Can you tell why so?

Answer (score 4):

SQL does not do arrays well.  You have mostly likely just done a `.ToString()` on the array of strings.
Try using `string.Join( ", ", mystrings)`.

As mentioned in the comments, this is not `third normal form`.  Search wikipedia for a good synopsis.

Comment: Is it not possible using .Tostring()?

Comment: No, ToString() on an array of strings uses Object.ToString() which just returns the class name.

Comment: Joining the strings together will work, but it's fragile (what if you have two strings ", " and ", " -- they look like the delimiter). You should structure your database better, so that any one field does not hold multiple values.

Comment: I agree.  The correct way is to have a table for the array of strings and insert a new row for each string in the array.  However, this answers OP's question.

Comment: i already have a string seperated with comma stored in database,i m splitting that string as  string[] strResult = strObj.Split(','); and now I have to insert the result returned by strResult in database column...

Comment: Having a new row for each string is not necessarily the "correct" way. If the array is a fixed sized and represents *n* different fields, it would be better to have one row and *n* fields. One row per string might lead you to an EAV model, which is probably overkill.